# Upgrade to the official environment and receive the following error "The client id provided is not registered with DocuSign"

Tags: docusignapi

I have applied the integrated key as a live key in the sandbox environment of docusign, and the status is: review passed,
However, I used the domain name of the official environment to obtain the authorization code. When logging into the official account, I received the following error: The client id provided is not registered with DocuSign
Does anyone know what I am missing?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8jFk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on passing the review for the DocuSign eSignature [API Go-Live process](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-steps).
However, you still need to take one more step after that. Which is, you need to go to your [developer sandbox (demo) env Admin](https://admindemo.docusign.com/), find your integration key and click "Review Status" where you see it passed, and then click "next" to log into the production (what you called "official" env to get that key activated in there. You would need to have a production account to proceed.

**Important:** You need administrator privileges to the production account to promote a key into it. If you do not have any valid account memberships, an error will be returned. Also note that certain account types, such as 30-day Free Trials and Freemium accounts, are not eligible for key promotion.